# Swift: Trying to create a locationManager class that handles all the location info and call it in my root view controller's View did Load

Tags: class, swift, ios8, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

I was attempting to make a class that handles location services and call in my root view controller however in doing so My app will not load, I get a indefinite black screen w/ the exception: thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ff...). Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Here's my code: (location manager class)

```
class LocationTracker: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let rootViewController = RootViewController()



func startTracking() {
  locationManager.delegate = self
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters

  locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
  locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

var currentLocation: CLLocation = manager.location

var coordinates: String = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude),\(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)"


println(" Locations data: \(locations)")

getLocationPlacemark(currentLocation: currentLocation)
}


  func displayLocationInfo  (#Placemark: CLPlacemark) {

locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

self.rootViewController.lblCurrentLocation.text = "\(Placemark.administrativeArea), \(Placemark.locality)"
}


func getLocationPlacemark (#currentLocation:CLLocation)-> Void {

CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation, completionHandler: { (placemark, error) -> Void in

  if error == nil && placemark.count > 0 {

    var pMark = placemark [0] as CLPlacemark

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

      self.displayLocationInfo(Placemark: pMark)
    })


  }else {

    self.rootViewController.lblCurrentLocation.text = "error!"
  }
})
}
```

Code for Root View Controller

```
let locationTracker = LocationTracker()

override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

 locationTracker.startTracking()
}
```

Comment: Place breakpoints in your code and single step through it. Then tell us exactly at what line the crash occurs.

Comment: Ok. so I placed a breakpoint and it seems as though there's an infinite loop of instantiation going on because I'm instantiating my rootViewController in the the LocationTracker. 

How do I change the properties of the objects on my root view controller without creating a new instance of my view controller?

Comment: You might think about creating a protocol which defines the needed functions and let your `rootViewController` be the delegate for `LocationTracker`.

Comment: But With Protocols I i still have to write the function in the rootViewController and that's what I'm trying to avoid. I want a class in a separate file to use the methods from the LocationManagerDelegate protocol and then use a method belonging to the class to call locationManager.startUpdatingLocation.